# Asp.net Mvc3 PartialView

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I wanna to have dynamic categories in my web site, Adding category in Admin area and show as a partialView in main page , it is clear that I should cache that , my category action is like this :

```
 public ActionResult Category()
        {

            var category = _categoryRepository.GetAllCategory();
            return PartialView(category);
        }
```

and my partialView is :

```
@model IEnumerable<Blog.Domain.Model.Category>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Category";
    Layout = null;
}
<div>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <ul>
            @Html.DisplayFor(x => item.Name)
        </ul>
    }
</div>
```

I'm not sure about above code and also have no idea about how to cache Category , please someone help me about that,thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this answers you question or not but to assign them a link just use Html.ActionLink() then have an action that take the selected category id as a parameter and loads a detailed view of the Category.

```
  @model IEnumerable<Blog.Domain.Model.Category>
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Category";
        Layout = null;
    }
    <div>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <ul>
                @Html.ActionLink(item.Name, "Detail". "Category", new {id = item.id)
            </ul>
        }
    </div>

public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {

            var category = _categoryRepository.GetById(id);
            //detail CategoryView
            return PartialView(category);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you really want, but have a look at `OutputCache` - http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/improving-performance-with-output-caching-cs

```
[OutputCache(Duration=10, VaryByParam="none")]
public ActionResult Category()
{
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer , but my main question was about dynamic category ,retrieve category from Db and show it in a partialview and render the partial in layout !

Comment: every website has a category list , wright? I have category list in my database and want to show them in a partialView, that is all !

Comment: but my trouble is that , how can I assign them a link ?

Comment: @EricNielsen you mention cache two times. What's that about? You are not being clear.